# Why does this comparison function return the wrong result?

Tags: javascript

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if(choice1 === choice2) {
        return"The result is a tie!";
    }
    else if(choice1 === "rock") {
        if(choice2 === "scissors"){
            return"rock wins";
        }
        else
        {
            return"paper wins";
        }
    else if(choice1 === "paper") {
        if(choice2 === "rock") {
            return"paper wins";
        }
        else
        {
            return"scissors wins";
        }
   }
}
};
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Yeah, were are you going wrong? Any output/error? Sth to listen to, regarding your name! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNOvlNZAACY ( That helps you keep down ).

Comment: I recognise this from codeacademy! Hah, I stopped that lesson last night right before making the compare function. Cool

Comment: What if `choice1==scissors?` or am I blind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just nested your `if`s incorrectly, do it like this:

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
  if(choice1 === choice2) {
    return "The result is a tie!";
  }
  else if(choice1 === "rock") {
    if(choice2 === "scissors"){
      return "rock wins";
    }
    else
    {
      return "paper wins";
    }
  }
  else if(choice1 === "paper") {
    if(choice2 === "rock") {
      return "paper wins";
    }
    else
    {
      return "scissors wins";
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to put a space between return and the value.

`return "The result is a tie!";` instead of `return"The result is a tie!";`

Take a look at http://jslint.com/ for syntax error.

Comment: Doesn't seem to throw an error, though: http://jsfiddle.net/oo7wy81t/

Comment: Naw, I think you're absolutely right. I just don't think that's the main problem with the OP's code. But the OP didn't really specify what was "wrong", either.